# Issue in Discord.py while linking JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm having an issue in linking Discord.py with JSON. Here's my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

    with open("muted_roles.json", "r") as f:
        muted_roles = json.load(f)
    muted_roles[str(guild.id)] = str(role.id)

    with open("muted_roles.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(muted_roles, f, indent=4)
```

Here's my error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\angel\Documents\python\Bots\dave\dave.py", line 59, in on_guild_join
    muted_roles = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I thank early for the assistance.

Comment: Your json file is empty, it should contain at least the open and close brackets (`{}`)

Comment: doesnt work and its too long to write here in comments

Comment: @aleissues Update your post with the new information then

Comment: You’re probably getting a KeyError indicating that the `str(guild.id)` key is not in the dict.

Comment: Can you show us your json file?

Comment: @loloToster my json file has two brackets { } separated by a line so line 1: { line 2: empty line 3: }

Comment: You cannot have an empty value, you have to add at least `[]`. Also you need the name in `""` and you have to add commas. So: `{"line 2": [], "line 3": []}`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is empty you should fill it with `{}` and it will fix!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29915681)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).